# A functional equation for harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions

Does there exist  a non zero function $u\in C(\mathbb{C})$, harmonic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{T}$ that satisfies the following equation:
$$u(z)+u(-z-2)=0\:\:\forall z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$$

Where $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z: |z|=1\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is a (unit?) disk or a domain?  $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: yes. $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z: |z|=1\}$

Comment: What is the difficulty?  The two disks ($z$ and $-z-2$) only have a single point of intersection (at $z = -1$).